# Is there a way to remove/edit name from multiple files on Windows?

Tags: file, export, photoshop, layer, photos

Basically I used the photoshop script to export all layers to jpegs. Other wise I would have to save hundereds of layers individually. That's all great. But the problem with that is, Photoshop added numaric numbers in each file names. Here's an eg.

Original: "1 white shoes", "2 blouse", "3 t-shirt".
Exported: "_001_1 white shoes", "_002_2 blouse", "_003_3 t-shirt".

So I would like to know if there is a faster way to remove those additional numbers in each name file? I rather not do them individually considering I have hundereds of files/photos.

Answer (score 0):

I found a photoshop script that does exactly what I want.  Here's the link. https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast